# remove duplicates records from design view

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-office

I made a query design to show the id(primary key) of two tables first table contains 17 record(17 id) and the second contains 15 record(15 id) so i want a query to view the 17 and 15 id but when i run it views 255 record which is (15 record *17 record), I want to remove duplicated records from query.
I use design view not SQL view.

Comment: Could you perhaps share the query that you're using here? I expect this might just an issue of there being a syntax misunderstanding causing the incorrect results.

Comment: is it possible to show the query?

Comment: What you have made is a *Cartesian* (multiplying) query.

Add in your query a join between the fields of the two tables that define the relation between these.

Comment: which type of join are you using and by what parameters are they joined with, can you show us?